# Issue with positioning of elements

Tags: html, css

I have a page which has a 'fixed' header. Now I want to position the content at 20% below the header, but the 'top' property doesn't seems to work. I tried to use 'left' and 'right' and they seemed to be working fine. Any pointers for this situation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add code or a fiddle.

Comment: My pointer would be provide the code for people to help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did something very similar here: http://firststop.herokuapp.com

We just used `padding-top: Xpx` in our body css, like this:

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

This basically makes the entire body of the page have a padding at the top, allowing you to keep the fixed header at the very top

The problem you have is the fixed element acts like a position: absolute element -- it doesn't take normal cascading preferences in the DOM, and thus cannot have any `position: relative` held against it

Answer (score 0):

Take CSS element`(margin-top:-Xpx;)`in Negative Values for the Content Div.

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like so:

```
.header{
position:absulote;
top:20%;
height:400px;
width:500px;
}
```